# Adding a LINQ where clause to a custom class

Tags: c#, linq, class, generics

I have the majority of what I need for this query but can't seem to get the last little bit. Basically, I need a `Where` clause applied to the `Book` section. For instance, I need to know which `Parent` has a `Child` who read book `1234`. So in this case my LINQ query would return a `Parent` class with both `John` and `Sally`s information *(but there are obviously a higher number of records that wouldn't be returned)*. Everything I setup is returning an error saying `Error   199 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` when I add `Books = grp1.Select(q=>q.Books)`. Any ideas?

### Classes

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent() { }

    public int ParentID { get { return _parentID; } set { _parentID = value; } }
    public List<Child> Children { get { return _child; } set { _child = value; } }
}
public class Child
{
    public Child() { }

    public int ChildID { get { return _childID; } set { _childID = value; } }
    public List<int> BookID { get { return _books; } set { _books = value; } }
}
```

### Table

```
 Parent ID |     Parent      | Child ID |     Child     |     Books 
1          | John            | 4        | Suzy          | 1234
1          | John            | 4        | Suzy          | 4567
1          | John            | 5        | James         | 6789
2          | Sally           | 4        | Suzy          | 1234
2          | Sally           | 4        | Suzy          | 4567
2          | Sally           | 5        | James         | 6789
```

### Query to Make a List of Parents ##

```
List<Parent> Parents = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("parent_id"))
    .Select(x => new Parent
    {
        ParentID = x.Key,
        Children = x.GroupBy(y => y.Field<int>("children")).Select(z => new Child
        {
            ChildID = z.Key,
            Books = z.Select(b => b.Field<int>("books")).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

### Desired Result

`List<Parent>`

**Parent Class Index 0:**
ParentID: 1
**Children Index 0:**
Child ID: 4
**BookID Index 0:** 1234, **Book Index 1:** 4567
**Children Index 1:**
Child ID: 5
**BookID Index 0:** 6789

... and so on.

Comment: `x, y, z` are not particularly informative names. If you're doing anything remotely complicated with a lambda variable, it's worth giving it a better name.

Comment: @ObliviousSage duly noted, this was just to get it working. I'm having a rough time understanding this query as it stands. I didn't feel like naming the variable would make sense until I understood 100% what each one represented... If that makes any sense.

Comment: Checked out the "SelectMany" ?

Comment: @Sasse I'm not sure how a character array is going to help me here? At least if I understand `SelectMany` corrrectly.

Comment: You're coming at it backwards, then. Build the query from simple pieces that you understand. Any time a lambda variable gets referenced more than once, that means it's time to give it a more descriptive name so you remember what it is when you add more pieces.

Comment: I think I missunderstood something, do you right now only have one table with the five columns presented? IE Parent name is written multiple times and Child name is written multiple times and Books written multiple times? ... or, do you have one table for Persons and one for Books and then relations between them?

Comment: @Sasse Basically the `dt` looks like the data provided and I am trying to return it into the classes provided. Like OUT of that datatable, I need to derive a list of `Parent` classes containing only students whom have read the specified book.

Comment: @Volearix Okay, then why is your "books" written as strings but you're trying to read them like integers? Is something missing?

Comment: @Sasse No, just a mistake. Changed to string. Was originally going to key off of a book id, but didn't need the additional class.

Comment: @Volearix You also need to change in the query. I did put together your code and it seems to work like it should, I'll post it like an answer even though it's not really an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use SelectMany instead of Select.**

`Books = grp1.Select(q => q.Books);` will transform each group member into its corresponding *List* of books, so you end up with an `IEnumerable<List<int>>`.

`SelectMany` does the same thing as `Select` but merges resulting IEnumerables into the parent IEnumerable. In this case, `Books = grp1.SelectMany(q => q.Books);` would give you an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. I gave it a shot, but another issue comes with the line `Child = z.Key`. It holds a list of `Child` and doesn't seem to evaluate correctly. I'm not sure if the `SelectMany` is helping due to the fact the other portion is errored out now.

Comment: This wasn't at all what he needed. I thought it was to at the beginning until I read the whole question.

Comment: @Volearix Since your example lists the identifier property as `child.ChildID` rather than `child.Key` that error makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following linq query will return your required result:

```
var parents = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    group p by p.Field<int>("parent_id")
                    into g
                    select new Parent
                    {
                        ParentId = g.Key,
                        Children =
                            (from c in g
                                group c by c.Field<int>("child_id")
                                into childGroup
                                select new Child
                                {
                                    ChildId = childGroup.Key,
                                    Books = childGroup.Select(c => c.Field<string>("books")).ToList()
                                }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did put together some code just to try your query out since I thought it looked pretty okay (except that you're reading books like strings like I told you in comments.

So this is not an answer but should be able to help you further.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Books { get; set; }
}

public class SS
{
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public int cid { get; set; }
    public string book { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void AAPlaying()
{
    var dt = new List<SS>() { };
    dt.Add(new SS() { pid = 1, cid = 4, book = "Grapes of ..."});
    dt.Add(new SS() { pid = 1, cid = 4, book = "Huck......." });
    dt.Add(new SS() { pid = 1, cid = 5, book = "The adven..." });
    dt.Add(new SS() { pid = 2, cid = 4, book = "Grapes of ..." });
    dt.Add(new SS() { pid = 2, cid = 4, book = "Huck......." });
    dt.Add(new SS() { pid = 2, cid = 5, book  = "The adven..." });


    List<Parent> Parents = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.pid)
        .Select(x => new Parent
        {
            ParentID = x.Key,
            Children = x.GroupBy(y => y.cid).Select(z => new Child
            {
                ChildID = z.Key,
                Books = z.Select(b => b.book).ToList()
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Okay, so your query returns everything, correct, but now I need JUST `Books` with a specific title.

Comment: @Volearix Okay, how do you need them? Do you need to select all parents and all child but just the right books or do you want to exclude the people who doesn't read the book. Just ad a ".Where(book => book.Title == "Grapes of ...") like this "z.Where(...).Select(...)". Otherwise you can ignore them from the beginning, like "dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Books == "Grapes of ...").GroupBy(...

Comment: First thing I have to say is that class 'SS' doesn't exist. To makes things just more sensible without ever touching the `SS` class I will update my example. See the updated question. I will outline exactly what I need in the answer as well. One sec.

Comment: updated the quesiton. Hopefully it makes sense what I'm looking for. See the desired reults area

Comment: @Volearix Of course SS doesn't exists for you, it's part of my example code to illustrate why my GroupBy's doesn't look like yours. SS class illustraties a row in your data-table without the ParentName and ChildName.

Comment: @Volearix I've looked at the updated question and I can only see the same thing. And you still haven't changed "b.Field<int>("books"))" to "b.Field<string>("books"))"